# Как достать код, который сканирует только QR? JS/HTML5

Tags: javascript

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/blob/master/minified/html5-qrcode.min.js, его размер составляет 367кб, учитывая что поддерживает много форматов, кроме сканирования QR, как мне очистить ненужные форматы и оставить только поддержку QR? Чтобы размер файла было максимально маленьким? Я новичок.